# how can I change a byte array from a wav file into a short array of the audio data

Tags: java, android

The purpose of this code is to pull the byte array from a wav file and change that byte array into audio data that I can then do signal processing with. There seems to be a problem with the code that parses the bytes into shorts. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Here is the code:

```
buttonDecode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
        buttonDecode.setEnabled(false);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        GraphView thegraph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.thegraph);
        series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
        double x,y;
        x = 0;

        try {
            //old wav byte array code

            ByteArrayOutputStream outt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(wavfile));

            int read;
            byte[] buff = new byte[RECORDER_SAMPLERATE]; //was 1024
            in.skip(44);
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
            {
                outt.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
            outt.flush();
            byte[] audioBytes = outt.toByteArray();
            int[] theRealData = null;

            //parsing the vector
            for(int i = 0; i < ((audioBytes.length)/2) ; i++) {
                byte highByte = audioBytes[(2*i)+1];
                byte lowByte = audioBytes[(2*i)];
                short value = twoBytesToShort(highByte,lowByte);
                theRealData[(i+1)/2] = value;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < theRealData.length;i++){
                int curByte = theRealData[i];
                y = (curByte);
                series.appendData(new DataPoint(x,y), true, theRealData.length);
                x = x + 1;
            }
            thegraph.addSeries(series);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
        buttonDecode.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);

    }
});
```

And the function:

```
public static short twoBytesToShort(byte b1, byte b2) {
        return (short) ((b1 << 8) | (b2 & 0xFF));
    }
```

Comment: FYI variable `x` and `y` are redundant. Use `new DataPoint(i, curByte)`

Comment: Where is the function twoBytesToShort() definition?

Comment: I added it at the bottom